# Photon Unity Networking 2 (PUN2): Issue with Room List Synchronization

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I'm encountering an issue with room list synchronization in Unity using Photon Unity Networking 2 (PUN2). Here's a detailed explanation of the problem:

I have implemented a room listing feature where available rooms are displayed in a scroll view. The issue arises when creating rooms from different instances of the game.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Start instance 1 and create a room.
2. Start instance 2 and create another room.
3. Observe the room list in instance 3.
   Expected Behavior:
   I expect both rooms created in instances 1 and 2 to be listed in the room view of instance 3.

**Actual Behavior:**
However, what happens is that the room created in instance 2 replaces the room created in instance 1 in the room list of instance 3.

**Code Snippets:**
Here's the relevant part of the code where I handle the OnRoomListUpdate callback:

```
public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> _roomList)
    {
        ClearRoomList();
        roomList = _roomList;
        
        foreach (RoomInfo room in roomList)
        {
            GameObject roomItemObj = Instantiate(roomItemPrefab,content);
            roomItemObj.transform.Find("Name of Room").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = room.Name;
            roomItemObj.transform.Find("players in room").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = room.PlayerCount+"/"+room.MaxPlayers;
            roomItemObj.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate {PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(room.Name);});


        }
        LogCurrentRoomList();
    }
```

Any help or insights into why the room list is not being consistently maintained across instances would be greatly appreciated.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Check that all instances are using the same region.  I believe you only see rooms in the region the instance is in.  I would also log your internal roomList before clearing, it (room list update) might only be sending the new room and not the full room list.